# Android: I can't open a PDF file from storage

Tags: android, pdf, uri, android-internal-storage

I am trying to make a PDF reader that allows the user to open a PDF file from the phone.

I start by making an intent that allows me to browse for the file

```
Intent openFileIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
openFileIntent.setType("*/*");
startActivityForResult(openFileIntent, FILE_OPEN_CODE);
```

Here is the onActivityResult:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == FILE_OPEN_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){
        Uri selectedFile = data.getData();
        try {
            openFile(selectedFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Once I have the Uri, I send it to the method that opens the PDF:

```
public void openFile(Uri fileUri) throws IOException {

    final int WIDTH = viewPDF.getWidth();
    final int HEIGHT = viewPDF.getHeight();
    String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + fileUri.getPath();
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(WIDTH, HEIGHT, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
    File pdfFile = new File(filePath);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Opened: " + filePath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    PdfRenderer renderer = new PdfRenderer(ParcelFileDescriptor.open(pdfFile, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY));
    currentPage = 0;
    Matrix matrix =  viewPDF.getImageMatrix();
    Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    renderer.openPage(currentPage).render(bitmap, rect, matrix, PdfRenderer.Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY);
    viewPDF.setImageMatrix(matrix);
    viewPDF.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

Now, the problem is that I get the following error:

```
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory
```

I am sure that the file exist, but the path that i get from the Uri is the following

> /storage/emulated/0/document/2443

2443 beign the File name I get instead of "MY_FILE.pdf"
I need to be able to get the file name to open the pdf on the renderer

Also, I have declared permissions in the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

and also manually prompted for permissions for android M and above

Comment: `but the path that i get from the Uri is the following

/storage/emulated/0/document/2443`. That is the value for uri.getPath(). But you better look at the content scheme obtained with uri.toString().

Comment: mind elaborating a little more?

Comment: If I try that I get
content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents./document/2443

Comment: So you see that you got a content scheme. Not a file system path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are constructing a non existent and impossible  filePath.

You should open an InputStream to read the file.

```
InputStream is  = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
```

Comment: Mind elaborating a little more?

Comment: What should i elaborate?